# How to switch from Ubuntu to Windows 7?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I have Windows 7 installed on C drive and installed Ubuntu on D drive. When I start the laptop, it starts with Ubuntu. I want to switch back to Windows 7. I don't want to lose any data on Windows 7. How can I uninstall Ubuntu using Ubuntu itself? I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

if you have windows 7 on one HDD and Ubuntu on another HDD all you have to do is remove the Ubuntu drive and it will boot into Windows 7.

This then saves your Ubuntu installation in case you ever decide you want to go back to it all the while keeping Windows 7

Comment: The problem is how do i remove it? I mean can you tell me the procedure. I have imp data on all 3 hdd's of mine. I can't install windows again coz i'll have to format the hardisk and i can't format the d drive coz it has has data n unfortunately ubuntu on it

Comment: If you have windows 7 on a seperate hard drive to Ubuntu then all you need to do is turn the power off to your machine (make sure you do this as)

remove the side panel of your computer tower

find the hard drive you have ubuntu on (if you do not know which one it is just pull out the power socket on each hard drive and reboot the computer it will either load into windows or wont (power sockets are white blocks about an inch wide and 1/4 inch thick))

once you have figured out which hard drive is your ubuntu one all you need to do is remove all the wires from the back of it

Comment: Umm. I'm talking about a laptop over here. Isn't there a way to shift back to windows?

Comment: ok if your talking about a laptop then its basically the same, if you have say 2 hard drives installed then your main one (hopefully running on Windows 7) will b located at the bottom of your machine normally just underneath the trackpad.  all you have to do is remove the screws and the plastic flap.  Alternatively you could put a windows installation cd into your machine select the drive with ubuntu on it go through the process of formatting the drive with that cd the exit the installation process.  Once that is done you will be able to get back into Windows

Comment: But i toldyou i have data in the drive i cant format at. I'm new to all this. Just tell me How do i know what drives are being used ? All i know is windows was installed on c drive. now how do i know on which drive is ubuntu installed?

Comment: how did you actually set it up ? are you dual booting or have you get a second hard drive running Ubuntu?

Comment: I just dont know what i did. How do i know its dual booting?

Comment: if its dual booting you will have an option when you first turn on your machine to choose which operating system to boot into.  

you can also find out by going to the little file icon on the left hand side of your screen right click it > open new window and then click file system on the right hand side (this should only show 22 folders and 3 files, most of the folders will be roughly 3 characters long.

Comment: just a matter of intrest have you got a spare 2.5" hard drive and a external usb enclosure?

Comment: Yes, I have 22 folders and 3 files.

Comment: I saw this comment and i can relate it to my problem, infact its the same , "It sounds to me like you probably deleted the Windows boot partition (A small, ~200Mb partition that Windows needs to be able to boot). To my knowledge, the only way to fix this is with a Windows Recovery Disc (or USB). As for finding out which version of Windows you have, I'm not sure. Is she has over 4GB memory installed then she's probably using a 64bit version, but I'm not sure how to check which specific version without actually booting into Windows. Hopefully somebody else can shed some light on that."

Comment: ok so that is your Ubuntu, by the looks of things you are running ubuntu on one hard drive and linux on another.  

what your best off doing is powering off your laptop, removing one of your hard drives if it dose not boot into ubuntu then you have got the ubuntu drive, then yopu need to get a windows 7 installtion disk insert that go to recovery mode and let that fix the boot option for u (it will do it automatically) once you have access to windows again you will be able to format your Ubuntu drive and use it as a storage area or leave it with ubuntu on its your choice

Comment: Ok, I can understand it a bit. What if i use an alternative? 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller

Comment: Will this work?

Comment: im assuming that would work (i have never used it before) however if you are going to use it make sure you delete Ubuntu and not Windows (as im guessing your wanting to keep windows).

once you have deleted Ubuntu you may need to use your Windows 7 installation disk to repair the boot sector

Comment: Thank you soo much. Can you send me your email id or something? I didnt install it properly this time , but i really liked ubuntu and wana install it properly once i have backed up my data.

Comment: if you need any further help you can get hold of me at matty@driftedmass.co.uk

if you want to install ubuntu as a lone installation (no windows) i can provide you with best ways to do it